# In a Pythonic way I like a list to become key values as list items in an existing dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've got a list and a dict. Now I want the items in the list to be key values in the dict and they have to be new lists. In a pythonic way :-)

I got it working. But I guess not in a real pythonic way.

```py
my_people = ['theo', 'Jan', 'Jason']
my_classes = {'class_1': {}, 'class_2': {}, 'class_3': {}}

my_classes['class_1'] = dict.fromkeys(my_people, 1)

for p in my_classes['class_1']:
  my_classes['class_1'][p] = []
```

So is there a way to make the items lists without the last for p in my_classes loop?

Output: `{'class_1': {'theo': [], 'Jan': [], 'Jason': []}, 'class_2': {}, 'class_3': {}}`

Comment: The code you provided does not work, `my_classes['class_1']` does not work when `my_classes` is a set

Comment: Show your expected output. Is it a dict of lists? nested dicts?

Comment: Since a dictionary has no order, I do not understand the intended maping. Occurrence in source code alone dies not help without an OrderedDict.

Comment: @guidot Well, starting in python 3.7 all dicts are inherently ordered.

Comment: @DeepSpace you are correct, I forgot to set a dict after class keys. Now it works, but still not pythonic I guess

Comment: @DeepSpace and I put a output at the end of it.

Comment: @tvdsluijs, why you need the for loop? As per your output, replacing `1` with `[]` in line `dict.fromkeys(my_people, 1)` should work. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @kuro Be very careful with that. Since `[]` is mutable, modifying one list will modify all others.

Comment: @DeepSpace, you are right. Didn't thought about that. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is as you show you can just use a dict comprehension:

```
my_people = ['theo', 'Jan', 'Jason']
my_classes = {'class_1': {}, 'class_2': {}, 'class_3': {}}

my_classes['class_1'] = {name: [] for name in my_people}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your variable `my_classes` isn't a dictionary. It's a set, a collection without duplicated itens.

For create the dictionary that you want you can use dict comprehension like that:

```
my_people = ['theo', 'Jan', 'Jason']
dictionary = { elem: []  for elem in my_people }
// -> {'theo': [], 'Jan': [], 'Jason': []}
```